# Перегрузка оператора ++

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте, есть класс к которому нельзя прибавить больше 1 значения, в классе идет индексация эллементов, и прочии действия)

Ну и покскольку меня немного раздражает все время писать

```
StringLink = StringLink + 1;
```

Кто-то скажет "а ты не пиши так, а пиши так `+=`", но это было для примера, да и наглядней писать так))

```
public static StringLink operator +(StringLink a, int b)
{
   //логика 
}
```

Прошу помочь перегрузить оператор `++`

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под `StringLink + 1`  и если `StringLink`  класс то вы должны перегружать оператор для членов вашего класса то есть кто и где будет добавляться `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class MyPoint
    {
        private int x, y, z;

        public MyPoint(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }

        public static MyPoint operator ++(MyPoint obj1)
        {
            obj1.x++;
            obj1.y++;
            obj1.z++;
            return obj1;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{x}, {y}, {z}";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyPoint point = new MyPoint(1, 12, -4);

            Console.WriteLine($"Точка: {point}.");
            point++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Точка: {point}.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*P.S. Большинство препроцессоров заменят `a = a + 1` или `a += 1` на `a++`, так как для инкремента и декремента в процессорах есть отдельные инструкции.*

Comment: [https://tproger.ru/translations/10-c-sharp-tips/](https://tproger.ru/translations/10-c-sharp-tips/) 5-ый пункт. Очень удобная вещь.

Comment: Семантика C# предполагает, что операторы не изменяют своих аргументов (как минимум видимо), а возвращают новый объект с новым значением.

Comment: @PetSerAl ну и что не так?

Comment: @BabaYaga *что не так?* Пост-инкремент ведёт себя некорректно: `MyPoint point = new MyPoint(1, 12, -4); var point2 = point++; Console.WriteLine($"Точка: {point2}.");`.

Comment: @PetSerAl сейчас бы новый объект создавать при инкременте... Зачем надо создавать ещё один объект? _Я не придираюсь, просто интересно._

Comment: @Jagailo Оператор пост-инкремента должен вернуть значение, которое было до выполнения оператора инкремента. Модифицируя объект in-place, Вы лишаете оператор пост-инкремента такой возможности. Собственно *создавать* ещё один объект не нужно. Нужно просто *не модифицировать* объект подлежащий инкременту. Если Вы можете обеспечить выполнение этого условия (*не модифицировать*) без создания нового объекта, то ничего плохого я в этом не вижу.